# Add text to image using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Hi i'm new to typescript i want to add text to image, and that image can be downloaded with the text.

I know how to do it with javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Image Text</title>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
    context.font = "20px Calibri";
 context.fillText("My TEXT!", 100, 200);
  };
  imageObj.src = 
 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
</script>
</body>``
</html>
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your javascript code is almost valid typescript code, all you need to do is to tell the compiler that `canvas` is of type [HTMLCanvasElement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L8592):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
    context.font = "20px Calibri";
    context.fillText("My TEXT!", 100, 200);
};

imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=var%20canvas%20%3D%20document.getElementById('myCanvas')%20as%20HTMLCanvasElement%3B%0Avar%20context%20%3D%20canvas.getContext('2d')%3B%0Avar%20imageObj%20%3D%20new%20Image()%3B%0AimageObj.onload%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20context.drawImage(imageObj%2C%2069%2C%2050)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20context.font%20%3D%20%2220px%20Calibri%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20context.fillText(%22My%20TEXT!%22%2C%20100%2C%20200)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AimageObj.src%20%3D%20'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.html5canvastutorials.com%2Fdemos%2Fassets%2Fdarth-vader.jpg'%3B))